# Installing Fabric On Windows (Error No Module Called Readline)

Tags: python, windows, deployment, fabric

I'm trying to use the **Fabric 0.1.1** deploy tool (http://docs.fabfile.org/) on Windows and we're running into an issue with the **readline** module.  I've been through various threads but can't seem to solve the issue.  It's important because we can't deploy applications from Windows based machines.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\dev\Desktop\deploy>fab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\Scripts\fab-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fabric==0.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\pkg_resources.py"
, line 277, in load_entry_point
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\pkg_resources.py"
, line 2180, in load_entry_point
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\pkg_resources.py"
, line 1913, in load
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\fabric.py", line 25, in <module>
**ImportError: No module named readline**
```

Installing the module results in:

```
**easy_install readline**
Searching for readline
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/readline/
Reading http://www.python.org/
Best match: readline 2.6.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/readline/readline-2.6.4.tar
.gz#md5=7568e8b78f383443ba57c9afec6f4285
Processing readline-2.6.4.tar.gz
Running readline-2.6.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\docume~1\ji81b9~1.che
\locals~1\temp\easy_install-pzkz1a\readline-2.6.4\egg-dist-tmp-szs2ps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c9', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 1671, in main
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 1659, in with_ei_usage
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 1675, in <lambda>
  File "c:\python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\sandbo
x.py", line 27, in run_setup
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\sandbo
x.py", line 63, in run
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg\setuptools\sandbo
x.py", line 29, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 93, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'symlink'
```

Has anybody solved this issue or can anybody suggest a workaround?

Comment: I'm working in Windows, but do use cygwin including python, fabric and git for version control and deployment. Absolutely no hassle, works great. 

You only have to change fabric/base.py and remove the value 'cygwin' in the line with win32api. But besides that minor bug, it works very smoothly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `readline` module you are trying to install with `easy_install` is for OS X, not windows.  There are Windows-compatible replacements for readline out there but perhaps you should first try updating `fabric` itself to a more current version ([0.9](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/) is out there now).

Grepping the source of the 0.9 version does not find any dependencies on `readline`.

Comment: This was my first idea, but any ideas on how this is installed via easy_install?   I think it might be a case of download the source and compile via cygwin...

Comment: Try `easy_install -U fabric` to get the latest version.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I started again from scratch with Fabric 0.9 and wrote up the steps that I took to install on Windows here: http://blog.oogly.co.uk/builddeploy/installing-and-running-fabric-on-windows

Answer (score 4):

Following these steps exactly worked for me:

1) Installed using the [MSI installer](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5.msi) for x86 from [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/).

2) Installed in the default C:\Python27 directory.

3) Create a new directory: C:\Python27\Scripts

4) Added C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts to the system path:

[image: Advanced system settings>Environment Variables>Path]

5) Download the [distribute_setup.py](http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py) from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) into C:\Python27\Scripts

6) Open a command line, navigate to C:\Python27\Scripts, run: 'python distribute_setup.py'

7) now run 'easy_install pip'

8) now run 'pip install fabric'

9) You should get an error saying PyCrypto couldn't install.  You can download the pre-build [Windows binary](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe) from [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto).  Run this to install PyCrypto.

10) run 'pip install fabric' again and it should say everything is installed.

11) in a different directory (let's say c:\dev\hello) create a fabfile.py and add the following code:

```
def hello(name="world"):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

12) cd to this directory and run 'fab hello:working'.  You should see output say

```
Hello working!

Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this [readline](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/PyReadline/Intro) a try. It is a module for Windows that allows additional features in IPython that aren't native and might work with what you are trying to do.

Comment: That worked for the readline issue but... I ran into a win32 module error (which I also fixed by installing pywin32).  However, now I'm stuck with a paramiko SSH exception - paramiko.SSHException: No suitable address family for x.x.x.x

Answer (score 2):

0.1.1 is an older version, I believe. I have no problem installing [Fabric](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/fabric/) on Windows with [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) (w/ [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/)):

```
C:\> pypm install fabric
Ready to perform these actions:
The following packages will be installed:
 fabric-0.9.0 pycrypto-2.0.1
Get: [pypm.activestate.com] fabric 0.9.0-1
Get: [pypm.activestate.com] pycrypto 2.0.1-1
Installing fabric-0.9.0
Fixing script C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\fab-script.py
Installing pycrypto-2.0.1
```

Comment: If this does work (I haven't tried it - I fixed up the base python install) you really should contact the Fabric guys and make sure they add a note to their installation instructions - would help to save people lots of time.

Comment: Jon, I made a request in their issue tracker: http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/127

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'm sure that will help a lot of people in the same situation...

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and run easy_install installer for your python version from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads . ie: `setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.6.exe`
2. On the command prompt, lauch `easy_install -U fabric` to install the last **fabric** release.

Answer (score 0):

Readline should be available with Cygwin, if you want to move your entire stack in that direction.