# Install Python Fabric on Windows

Tags: python, windows, fabric

How to get a working Python Fabric installation on Windows?

Comment: It isn't designed for it, but it does work on it, as illustrated by my own answer below (which was the reason for this question -> so I could share my solution). Please upvote the question again, so people can find this help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need Cygwin for Fabric on Windows. This duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917193/installing-fabric-on-windows-error-no-module-called-readline. You even get multiple hits when googling for 'python install fabric on windows'

Comment: Well then, give your instructions for an easy, WORKING Fabric install on Windows in the answers below. The question didn't state that solutions had to include Cygwin...

Comment: Since you edited your comment to point at the duplicates on Stackoverflow and Google: most of those instructions are hugely complicated, with code fixes left and right, are outdated and most of the time don't even work.

Comment: Btw: it doesn't duplicate the linked question, because that deals specifically with some readline error people get. Which in my solution below, isn't even an issue.

Comment: follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16625327/311525) instructions

Answer (score 27):

fabric installs just fine on Windows, but you will need to either:

1. have a compiler installed to build the pycrypto dependency during setup.If you don't have one already, install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [you can use the free version of MSVC](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/).
2. install pre-built Windows binaries for pyCrypto [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto).

I install it in a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) like so:

```
virtualenv fabenv
fabenv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install fabric
```

Another Tip: When you have it up and running you can [use pageant to load your ssh keys](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter9.html) and avoiding using password-based authentication

Comment: One can now also download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7, instead of installing the full Visual Studio:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Answer (score 7):

Solution using Cygwin:

- Install Cygwin
- Select packages: Python, Gcc, Wget and Openssh
- In Cygwin run: `python --version` to verify your Python version
- From http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools download the *.egg* version of setuptools (NOT the Windows .exe), for your version of Python.
- In Cygwin run: `sh setuptools-*.egg` to install the downloaded setuptools package
- In Cygwin run: `easy_install pip` (I just like Pip, I think you could the next step with easy_install as well)
- In Cygwin run: `pip install fabric`
- And now comes the crucial part: if the above step fails with some "could not remap xxx.dll" error, on the install of the Python ssh package then:
- Exit Cygwin
- Start a cmd.exe an in it run: `c:\cygwin_path\bin\ash.exe`
- In the ash shell run: `/bin/rebaseall`
- In Cygwin retry: `pip install fabric`, it should succeed now :)