# How to run a Python script remotely

Tags: python, remote-access

We run many Python scripts for data processing tasks.  We have a modeling computer that has been upgraded to provide the best performance for these tasks, but it is shared by many people that all need to run different scripts on it at the same time.

Is it possible for me to run a Python script remotely on that machine from my laptop while others are either directly logged into it or also remotely running a script?

Is SSH a possibility?  I haven't ever run any scripts remotely aside from logging in via remote desktop.  Ideally, I could start the Python script on that remote machine, but all the messages would be visible to me on my laptop.  Does this sound doable?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention all machines are running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is definitely the way to go and also have a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/).

Regarding your edit. You can [use Fabric on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000380/install-python-fabric-on-windows). And I think that using SSH on Windows will be a bit easier than [dancing with their Powershell's remoting capabilities](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/).

Comment: totally agree, `fabric` has been a lifesaver for me

Comment: Can I log in via SSH while someone else is also logged?

Answer (score 0):

SSH does seem like it should meet your needs.

You could also consider setting up an [iPython notebook server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/htmlnotebook.html#quick-howto-running-a-public-notebook-server) that everyone could use.

Its got nice [parallel processing capabilities](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html) if you are doing some serious number crunching.