# shlex.split with posix=false is not working (search for a file remotely)

Tags: python, posix, shlex

```
gap = "dir c:\\PROGRA~2\\td\\conf\\ga.db3"
print gap
cmd = shlex.split('cmd "/c ' + gap+'"', posix=False)
print cmd
o = subprocess.call(cmd)
print o
```

The above script I am running on windows and it doesnt work at all. I just want to search a file "ga.db3" exists or not remotely. Please let me know.

```
The output is: File Not Found
```

Comment: I don't have enough Windows experience to answer this. Frankly I don't even know how you're going to execute some arbitrary thing on a remote WIndows server! You're going to have to resort to some specific Windows solution(s) IHMO -- If this were UNIX/Linux I'd say use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/)'s ``fabric.contrib.files.exists`` function over SSH.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000380/install-python-fabric-on-windows http://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

You must use `posix=True` to remove escaped quotes.

For difference between POSIX and non-POSIX read below the line or from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#parsing-rules).

---

### [Parsing rules in non-POSIX mode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#parsing-rules)

> - Quote characters are not recognized within words (`Do"Not"Separate` is
>     parsed as the single word `Do"Not"Separate`)
> - Escape characters are not recognized
> - Enclosing characters in quotes preserve the literal value of all characters within the quotes;
> - Closing quotes separate words (`"Do"Separate` is parsed as `"Do"` and `Separate`)
> - If whitespace_split is False, any character not declared to be a word character, whitespace,
>     or a quote will be returned as a single-character token. If it is
>     True, shlex will only split words in whitespaces
> - EOF is signaled with an empty string (`''`)
> - It’s not possible to parse empty strings, even if quoted.

### [Parsing rules in POSIX mode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#parsing-rules)

> - Quotes are stripped out, and do not separate words (`"Do"Not"Separate"` is parsed as the single word `DoNotSeparate`)
> - Non-quoted escape characters (e.g. `'\'`) preserve the literal value of the next character
>     that follows
> - Enclosing characters in quotes which are not part of
>     escapedquotes (e.g. `"'"`) preserve the literal value of all characters within the quotes
> - Enclosing characters in quotes which are part of
>     escapedquotes (e.g. `'"'`) preserves the literal value of all characters
>     within the quotes, with the exception of the characters mentioned in
>     escape. The escape characters retain its special meaning only when
>     followed by the quote in use, or the escape character itself.
>     Otherwise the escape character will be considered a normal character.
>     EOF is signaled with a None value
> - Quoted empty strings (`''`) are allowed